# Sequence definition of continuous function: what if there is no converging sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

This is an exploratory question.

> **Assumption**: For all infinite sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to
> $x_\infty$, $f(x_n) $converges to $f(x_\infty)$.
>
> **Definition**: if the assumption is satisfied by $f$, then it is
> continuous.

Let's consider a space $X$ with no infinite sequence that converges (expect the trivial sequence $\forall n, x_n=x$ ). The Assumption above is trivially satisfied; therefore any $f$ is continuous. What's wrong my logic?

My question: what is the minimal assumption needed for the existence of decreasing sequence of $f$: $f(x_1)<f(x_2)<...$?

Comment: Any space with at least one element has a sequence that converges. For take $x \in X$; it is easy to see that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} = x$ converges to $x$.

Comment: @K.Jiang truly sorry that this is a exploratory question. I add your idea

Comment: Are you considering metric spaces or general topological spaces?

Comment: Also, what is a decreasing sequence in a setting without an order relation?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur $f$ is a real function so the order relation is the natural order on R.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your logic.  If the only convergent sequences are sequences that are eventually constant, then all functions are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If you are permitting only eventually constant functions to converge, then I think all your points are isolated and you have a discrete topology. In particular, any function is continuous because any preimage will be open.

If you want to have a sequence $x_n\to x_\infty$ with a possibly continuous function such that $f(x_n)>f(x_{n+1})$ for all $n$, then the sequence of points must be distinct and have $x_\infty$ as an accumulation point. This can't happen in a discrete topological space.

By the way, your definition of continuity by sequences fits more with the notion of [Sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) or [1st countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space).